# How to shrink a chart / filter out "zero" values so results aren't crammed into a tiny space

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a line chart that represents two columns of numerical data. The chart's X axis shows all dates from the beginning to the end of 2020, the Y axis is the values of the two columns.

The problem is I have only one entry for the two Y values, and the chart shows all values from the first date to the last date (which would be zero except for the one entry). What happens is the chart's line data is crammed to the far left because it's including all values in the two data columns instead of the values that aren't zero.

How can I alter the chart so it only shows the Y values that have been entered so I can clearly see the graph? Basically just filter out all "zero" entries in the columns so I only see the filled-in values represented in the chart?

Comment: It's financial data...what's the best way to share it so I don't give out anything I don't feel comfortable with?

Comment: the best way is you give a new sheet that looks like your financial data but without your actual data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to look for a solution related to your specific case and I haven't seen a built-in way to do it.

I've built a simple Apps Script that will look for the first empty value in the second column to update the chart range on every edit made.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Assuming that your X-axis is in the first column
  // and your Y-axis is in the second
  var rang = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow());

  var rangValues = rang.getValues()

  // Checking the first value in the second column that is not defined
  for(var i = 0; i < rangValues.length; i++){
    if( rangValues[i] == undefined || rangValues[i] == "" || rangValues[i] == 0 ){
      break;
    }
  }

  var finalRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, i, 2);

  // Updating the chart with the new Range
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
               .clearRanges()
               .addRange(finalRange)
               .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

This is working for me, If you are not familiar with Apps Script, you could try to look in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) before implementing this.

If your data is arranged in other way let me know so I can adapt this script to suit your needs.

---

Also another workaround that could try to do, without using App Script, is create a new sheet and filter that data with some sheets formula:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B, "select A, B where B>0 and B is not null")
```

[image: Formula and new sheet]

The drawback of this solution is that you need to replicate your data through `QUERY`. But if you are not comfortable with Apps Script.

---

I think that what you want to do is not a crazy idea so you could report it and try to get it implemented by google.

[image: Report Feedback]

Comment: This works, only the values will be "0" and not null or undefined.

Comment: Do you want to stop at first 0? You could just add that condition in the `for` loop. If that's not the case could you please provide a clearer example of what you want?

Comment: I have modified the code to add the condition to break `for` loop in case there is a 0. If you want a more specific behavior. You will need to define it better.

Comment: I insert the chart, run the code, and it gives me a single dot. https://imgur.com/a/zcaHIIr

Comment: Have you changed the columns in the script to fit your needs. At stated in the answer this code is thought to run in the first at second column.

Comment: It works now, odd. I'd like the script to run for a chart with X axis as dates and Y axis as two columns of data. So column A is X axis, Column B is one line for Y, column C is another line for Y. Is this feasible?

Comment: What you say is feasible and possible you will need to add another column to the `finalRange`.  Change the initialization of the variable to `var finalRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, i, 3);` . Also if you have another question you should open another post asking there your new question so we don't create a  mess pseudo solution here in the comments. Remember to accept answers that have [solved your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I have added a non Apps Script solution in my answer, maybe you are more comfortable with this one.